# Copy Records From Access Table To Access Table

Tags: c#, oledbconnection, oledbcommand

In C# I am trying to insert records from one access table to another access table, but I get the above error message.  What is causing this error (OleDbException: No value given for one or more required parameters) as it is a straight Select * statement?

```
OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=P:\\Source.mdb;");
connection.Open();
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO [;DATABASE=V:\\Destination.mdb;].[table1] SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE company = 2", connection);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
connection.Close();
```

EDIT --- Error in Insert Statement

```
OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=P:\\Source.mdb;");
connection.Open();
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO [;DATABASE=V:\\Destination.mdb;].[table1] (Name, Address, Phone, RepeatCustomer) SELECT Name, Address, Phone, RepeatCustomer FROM table1 WHERE company = 2", connection);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
connection.Close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are the two tables identical? You'd get this error if the column order and/or types don't match. It's much better form to explicitly define the columns you want to modify:

```
INSERT INTO [;DATABASE=V:\\Destination.mdb;].[table1] (col1,col2) SELECT col1,col2 FROM table1 WHERE company = 2
```

this way, order doesn't matter, and you aren't trying to add to columns that don't exist.

Comment: I updated my code above to show listing columns, now it throws an Error in Insert Statement

Comment: Yes the tables are identical.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue copying to the same table.  This sample of just two fields  worked for me:

```
INSERT INTO [Orders] (CUST, PART_NUMBE) SELECT CUST, PART_NUMBE FROM [orders]
WHERE [OrderNumber]= 23979
```